# Trying to find two words before and after a group of words with regex

Tags: python, regex

```
sentence = "I love the grand mother bag i bought . I love my sister's ring "

import re

regex = re.search('(\w+){2}the grand mother bag(\w+){2}', sentence)
print(regex.groups())
```

I should have extracted: I love and I bought.

Any idea where I went wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Change your regex: \w does not match word but a character so you extract only 2 characters:

```
>>> re.search('(\w+\s+\w+)\s+the grand mother bag\s+(\w+\s+\w+)', sentence).groups()

('I love', 'i bought')
```

Comment: Great solution, though for the explanation, I think OP just forgot the whitespace since they wrote `\w+`.